# Converting singleton to service

Tags: android, service, singleton

I have a singleton set up to hold global variables throughout the lifespan of my app. It works, but I notice when I close my app, I lose these variables which means started services can't access to them. I think the best fix is to convert this to a started service that runs in the background, but I'm not sure how to do it :/ Could anyone help out? This is the class right now:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UserValues {
    private static UserValues mInstance= null;

    protected UserValues(){}

    ArrayList<FavRoute> favorites;
    ArrayList<BusRoute> stops;
    HashMap<Integer, LatLng> geo;

    //CONSTANTS
    final int ADD_RESULT_KEY = 2;

    public static synchronized UserValues getInstance(){
        if(null == mInstance){
            mInstance = new UserValues();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, the best solution is to save the data to a file/`SharedPreferences`/database, so that when your process is terminated and later started, you can read the data back in.

Comment: I access this data approximately once per second. Would accessing SharedPreferences that often be an issue? I know it stores data in the devices actual memory which is why I'm cautious

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "access". `SharedPreferences` are automatically cached. Your only disk I/O is when you first read them in for your process and whenever you `apply()` your `SharedPreferences.Editor` to change them. That being said, bear in mind that doing *anything* once per second while your app is in the background may cause users to threaten you with pitchforks and torches, due to the battery drain that you may cause.

Comment: @CommonsWare is doing a small loop once per second that bad? I'm planning on updating an ETA in a notification once per second, showing minutes:seconds remaining. If that's a drain, I could change it to just minutes, and when it's less than a minute say "less than a minute remaining" or something alike

Comment: "I'm planning on updating an ETA in a notification once per second, showing minutes:seconds remaining" -- doing IPC every second, and forcing a service to stay running to make it happen, will tie up system RAM and consume some battery. At the very least, make this optional.

Comment: There's a settings toggle for it :) I think I'll make it so it only updates every 30-60 seconds instead and switch everything over to SharedPreferences. Thanks!